# PHP Desktop secure PHP code

Tags: php, source-code-protection

I am using [PHP Desktop Chrome 57 with PHP 7.1 for Windows](https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/wiki/Download-Chrome) and I am looking for a way to protect my PHP source code from changes.

I have already read the options shown in the [corresponding article from PHP Desktop](https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/wiki/Knowledge-Base#how-do-i-protect-php-sources-in-the-www-directory) and have tested the free options without having done. One of the commercial products I did not want to test because of the rather small project and I do not want to spend so much money for it.

Not all PHP files need to be encrypted, it would be enough to encrypt only certain sensitive files.

Obfucation I have already tried but it seems to me to insecure.

Do you know more possibilities that I can test?

Thanks!

Comment: basic answer- you can't

Answer (score 0):

After a long search I found [phpv3eps](https://phpv3eps.markuspro.de/). I have only tested the free version but this has already done everything I needed.

Not really well documented, but with that I can protect sensitive parts of my PHP source code.

Maybe this extension will help someone else.